# calculando data no update mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Bom preciso de dar update em minhas contas que estão vencidas a mais de 5 meses, queria fazer isso direto no mysql. O update está assim:

```
UPDATE contas
SET baixa_valivade = true
WHERE data_vencimento (Preciso verificar se já esta vencida a mais de 5 meses)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use o [**DATE_ADD()**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_add.asp):

```
UPDATE contas
SET baixa_valivade = true
WHERE data_vencimento BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -5 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

---

Se a necessidade for atualizar os itens com data de atraso maior que 5 meses, o código ficaria o seguinte:

```
UPDATE contas
SET baixa_valivade = true
WHERE data_vencimento < DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -5 MONTH)
```

Comment: Bom testei aqui e não funcionou muito bem, tenho 2 contas. 2017-09-26 e 2018-07-26. Deveria atualizar a conta 2017-09-26, porém esta atualizando a conta 2018-07-26.

Comment: pela data de hoje, 5 meses pra trás pegaria a de 07/18 (-2 meses).. a 09/12 está -12 meses.. não entendi o erro =p

Comment: Bom acho que eu não soube explicar direito, o update deve ser dado nas contas que tem mais de 5 meses atrasadas. A conta 09/17 tem mais de 5 meses atrasadas e a conta 07/18 ainda não completou 5 meses.

Comment: saquei.. atualizei a resposta, veja se resolve!

Comment: Ok, deu certo. Obrigado